# С помощью vk api пытаюсь выводить данные в react, но выдает ошибку, что делаю не так?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vkontakte-api, fetch

Использую vk api, с помощью fetch пытаюсь получить данные, но в итоге в консоли выдает ошибку:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=группа&count=10&access_token=токен&v=5.122' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

no-corse писать уже пробовал, в итоге ошибка проподает, но данные так и не приходят.
Запрос:

```
fetch("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=группа&count=10&access_token=токен&v=5.122",{
    method: 'GET'
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log("Ошибка при получении данных...")
        }
    )
```

Comment: может со своего сервера посылать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обхода CORS, используйте JSONP, как описано у них в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://api.vk.com/method/getProfiles?uid=66748&access_token=533bacf...&callback=callbackFunc";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
function callbackFunc(result) {
   console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Политика CORS блокирует запросы, которые инициируются именно скриптами браузера. Насколько я помню,не все вк API позволяют осуществлять запросы таким образом, и в вашем случае, вероятно, ошибка именно по этой причине. Этот запрос вы можете осуществлять с сервера